# CSP issue with createObjectURL on WebkitBlobBuilder

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am facing an issue with CSP in my extension...

I use a content script in order to change images on websites. My content script was adding his own images to websites so I had the following warning :

```
[Report Only] Refused to load image from 'chrome://extension/xxx/...' 
because of Content-Security-Policy. 
The page at https://plus.google.com/u/0/hot displayed insecure content 
from chrome://extension/xxx/....
```

So I added the following line to my manifest :

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src *"
```

and the warning disappeared...

Now, I need to modify images, to do that, I write them to a canvas, get the dataURL and convert it into a WebkitBlobBuilder to avoid the memory leak due to src change on img tag (with a blob, I can revoke it once it has been used and it freed the memory...)

Part of the code :

```
  //Code to create a blob from dataURI 
  base.dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI, callback) { 
      var byteString; 
      if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) 
          byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]); 
      else 
          byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]); 
      var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length); 
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab); 
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) { 
          ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i); 
      } 
      var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder(); 
      bb.append(ab); 
      return bb.getBlob(mimeString); 
  }; 

  //Code to display the blob on an image : 
  //Write image on a canvas : 
  base.ctx.putImageData(cData, img.leftPos, img.topPos); 
  //Get a blob 
  var blobData = base.dataURItoBlob(base.canvas.toDataURL("image/png")); 
  //Create an URL from the blob 
  var urlfile = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(dataBlob); 
  //set it on the img tag 
  img.attr("src", urlfile); 
  //Revoke the blob once loaded 
  img.load(function() { 
    window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(urlfile); 
  });
```

This code works great.... 
There is no more memory leak due to src change on my img tag.

BUT I have this warning :

```
[Report Only] Refused to load image from 'blob:https%3A%2F 
%2Fplus.google.com/52ac1648-64d6-4fce-bb35-537d939d5007' because of 
Content-Security-Policy. 
The page at https://plus.google.com/u/0/hot displayed insecure content 
from blob:https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com/52ac1648-64d6-4fce- 
bb35-537d939d5007.
```

Why does the default-src from content policy does not applied to 
blobs ??

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like this might be a bug in the CSP implementation, so far as  I can tell, blobs should be recognized as a valid scheme: can you file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/?

Answer (score 0):

According the CSP Spec:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/bcf1c45f312f/csp-unofficial-draft-20110303.html#data--uris-must-not-be-permitted

> 4.1.3 data: URIs must not be permitted

So you have to whitelist it in your manifest

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src data:
```